# mysql - slow query on order by id - primary key

Tags: mysql

Following is the table structure:

```
create table mooprod.users
(
    id int unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    name varchar(100) default '' not null,
    email varchar(100) default '' not null,
    password varchar(100) default '' not null,
    salt varchar(16) null,
    role_id tinyint unsigned default 2 not null,
    avatar varchar(255) default '' not null,
    photo varchar(255) default '' not null,
    created datetime null,
    last_login datetime null,
    search_city varchar(255) default 'Chennai' not null,
    photo_count smallint(5) unsigned default 0 not null,
    friend_count smallint(5) unsigned default 0 not null,
    notification_count tinyint unsigned default 0 not null,
    friend_request_count tinyint unsigned default 0 not null,
    blog_count smallint(5) unsigned default 0 not null,
    topic_count smallint(5) unsigned default 0 not null,
    group_count smallint(5) unsigned default 0 not null,
    event_count smallint(5) unsigned default 0 not null,
    conversation_user_count tinyint unsigned default 0 not null,
    video_count smallint(5) unsigned default 0 not null,
    gender varchar(10) default '' not null,
    birthday date null,
    active tinyint(1) unsigned default 1 not null,
    confirmed tinyint(1) unsigned default 1 not null,
    code varchar(100) default '' not null,
    notification_email tinyint(1) unsigned default 1 not null,
    timezone varchar(64) default '' not null,
    ip_address varchar(50) default '' not null,
    privacy tinyint(2) unsigned default 1 not null,
    username varchar(128) default '' not null,
    about text not null,
    featured tinyint(1) unsigned default 0 not null,
    lang varchar(4) default '' not null,
    hide_online tinyint(1) unsigned default 0 not null,
    cover varchar(256) default '' not null,
    approved tinyint(1) default 0 not null comment 'admin approved user feature',
    is_social tinyint(1) default 0 not null,
    has_active_subscription tinyint(1) default 0 not null,
    receive_message_from_non_friend tinyint(1) unsigned default 1 not null,
    send_email_when_send_message tinyint(1) default 1 not null,
    request_friend_email tinyint(1) default 1 not null,
    notification_setting text null,
    profile_type_id int default 1 not null,
    package_select int default 0 not null,
    who_can_see_gender int default 0 not null,
    chat_count int default 0 not null,
    constraint email
        unique (email)
)
collate=utf8_unicode_ci;

create index active
    on mooprod.users (active);

create index gender
    on mooprod.users (gender);

create index id_active_index
    on mooprod.users (id, active);

create index role_id
    on mooprod.users (role_id);

create index username
    on mooprod.users (username);


create table mooprod.roles
(
    id int unsigned auto_increment
        primary key,
    name varchar(128) default '' not null,
    is_admin tinyint(1) unsigned default 0 not null,
    is_super tinyint(1) unsigned default 0 not null,
    params text not null,
    core tinyint(1) unsigned default 0 not null
)
collate=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

I am trying to run following query:

```
SELECT `User`.`id`,
       `User`.`name`,
       `User`.`email`,
       `User`.`password`,
       `User`.`salt`,
       `User`.`role_id`,
       `User`.`avatar`,
       `User`.`photo`,
       `User`.`created`,
       `User`.`last_login`,
       `User`.`search_city`,
       `User`.`photo_count`,
       `User`.`friend_count`,
       `User`.`notification_count`,
       `User`.`friend_request_count`,
       `User`.`blog_count`,
       `User`.`topic_count`,
       `User`.`group_count`,
       `User`.`event_count`,
       `User`.`conversation_user_count`,
       `User`.`video_count`,
       `User`.`gender`,
       `User`.`birthday`,
       `User`.`active`,
       `User`.`confirmed`,
       `User`.`code`,
       `User`.`notification_email`,
       `User`.`timezone`,
       `User`.`ip_address`,
       `User`.`privacy`,
       `User`.`username`,
       `User`.`about`,
       `User`.`featured`,
       `User`.`lang`,
       `User`.`hide_online`,
       `User`.`cover`,
       `User`.`approved`,
       `User`.`is_social`,
       `User`.`has_active_subscription`,
       `User`.`receive_message_from_non_friend`,
       `User`.`send_email_when_send_message`,
       `User`.`request_friend_email`,
       `User`.`notification_setting`,
       `User`.`profile_type_id`,
       `User`.`package_select`,
       `User`.`who_can_see_gender`,
       `User`.`chat_count`,
       `Role`.`id`,
       `Role`.`name`,
       `Role`.`is_admin`,
       `Role`.`is_super`,
       `Role`.`params`,
       `Role`.`core`
FROM `mooprod`.`users` AS `User`
         LEFT JOIN `mooprod`.`roles` AS `Role` ON (`User`.`role_id` = `Role`.`id`)
WHERE `User`.`active` = '1'
ORDER BY `User`.`id` desc
LIMIT 15, 15
```

It takes more than 1.7 seconds to come back.
Explain shows following:

```
1   SIMPLE  User        range   PRIMARY,id_active_index,active  PRIMARY 4       96985   100 Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE  Role        ALL PRIMARY             5   100 Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)
```

But following query without join comes back in 0.173 seconds:

```
SELECT `User`.`id`,
       `User`.`name`,
       `User`.`email`,
       `User`.`password`,
       `User`.`salt`,
       `User`.`role_id`,
       `User`.`avatar`,
       `User`.`photo`,
       `User`.`created`,
       `User`.`last_login`,
       `User`.`search_city`,
       `User`.`photo_count`,
       `User`.`friend_count`,
       `User`.`notification_count`,
       `User`.`friend_request_count`,
       `User`.`blog_count`,
       `User`.`topic_count`,
       `User`.`group_count`,
       `User`.`event_count`,
       `User`.`conversation_user_count`,
       `User`.`video_count`,
       `User`.`gender`,
       `User`.`birthday`,
       `User`.`active`,
       `User`.`confirmed`,
       `User`.`code`,
       `User`.`notification_email`,
       `User`.`timezone`,
       `User`.`ip_address`,
       `User`.`privacy`,
       `User`.`username`,
       `User`.`about`,
       `User`.`featured`,
       `User`.`lang`,
       `User`.`hide_online`,
       `User`.`cover`,
       `User`.`approved`,
       `User`.`is_social`,
       `User`.`has_active_subscription`,
       `User`.`receive_message_from_non_friend`,
       `User`.`send_email_when_send_message`,
       `User`.`request_friend_email`,
       `User`.`notification_setting`,
       `User`.`profile_type_id`,
       `User`.`package_select`,
       `User`.`who_can_see_gender`,
       `User`.`chat_count`
FROM `mooprod`.`users` AS `User`
WHERE `User`.`active` = 1
  AND `User`.id > 0
ORDER BY `User`.`id` desc
LIMIT 15, 15
```

I also tried fake querying id based on SO answer

```
SELECT `User`.`id`,
       `User`.`name`,
       `User`.`email`,
       `User`.`password`,
       `User`.`salt`,
       `User`.`role_id`,
       `User`.`avatar`,
       `User`.`photo`,
       `User`.`created`,
       `User`.`last_login`,
       `User`.`search_city`,
       `User`.`photo_count`,
       `User`.`friend_count`,
       `User`.`notification_count`,
       `User`.`friend_request_count`,
       `User`.`blog_count`,
       `User`.`topic_count`,
       `User`.`group_count`,
       `User`.`event_count`,
       `User`.`conversation_user_count`,
       `User`.`video_count`,
       `User`.`gender`,
       `User`.`birthday`,
       `User`.`active`,
       `User`.`confirmed`,
       `User`.`code`,
       `User`.`notification_email`,
       `User`.`timezone`,
       `User`.`ip_address`,
       `User`.`privacy`,
       `User`.`username`,
       `User`.`about`,
       `User`.`featured`,
       `User`.`lang`,
       `User`.`hide_online`,
       `User`.`cover`,
       `User`.`approved`,
       `User`.`is_social`,
       `User`.`has_active_subscription`,
       `User`.`receive_message_from_non_friend`,
       `User`.`send_email_when_send_message`,
       `User`.`request_friend_email`,
       `User`.`notification_setting`,
       `User`.`profile_type_id`,
       `User`.`package_select`,
       `User`.`who_can_see_gender`,
       `User`.`chat_count`,
       `Role`.`id`,
       `Role`.`name`,
       `Role`.`is_admin`,
       `Role`.`is_super`,
       `Role`.`params`,
       `Role`.`core`
FROM `mooprod`.`users` AS `User`
         LEFT JOIN `mooprod`.`roles` AS `Role` ON (`User`.`role_id` = `Role`.`id`)
WHERE `User`.`active` = 1
  AND `User`.id > 0
ORDER BY `User`.`id` desc
LIMIT 15, 15;
```

But still end up with same, I do not understand why a simple join with roles would make the query so bad.

Although following query comes back in 300ms

```
SELECT `User`.`id`,
       `User`.`name`,
       `User`.`email`,
       `User`.`password`,
       `User`.`salt`,
       `User`.`role_id`,
       `User`.`avatar`,
       `User`.`photo`,
       `User`.`created`,
       `User`.`last_login`,
       `User`.`search_city`,
       `User`.`photo_count`,
       `User`.`friend_count`,
       `User`.`notification_count`,
       `User`.`friend_request_count`,
       `User`.`blog_count`,
       `User`.`topic_count`,
       `User`.`group_count`,
       `User`.`event_count`,
       `User`.`conversation_user_count`,
       `User`.`video_count`,
       `User`.`gender`,
       `User`.`birthday`,
       `User`.`active`,
       `User`.`confirmed`,
       `User`.`code`,
       `User`.`notification_email`,
       `User`.`timezone`,
       `User`.`ip_address`,
       `User`.`privacy`,
       `User`.`username`,
       `User`.`about`,
       `User`.`featured`,
       `User`.`lang`,
       `User`.`hide_online`,
       `User`.`cover`,
       `User`.`approved`,
       `User`.`is_social`,
       `User`.`has_active_subscription`,
       `User`.`receive_message_from_non_friend`,
       `User`.`send_email_when_send_message`,
       `User`.`request_friend_email`,
       `User`.`notification_setting`,
       `User`.`profile_type_id`,
       `User`.`package_select`,
       `User`.`who_can_see_gender`,
       `User`.`chat_count`,
       `Role`.`id`,
       `Role`.`name`,
       `Role`.`is_admin`,
       `Role`.`is_super`,
       `Role`.`params`,
       `Role`.`core`
from (
         SELECT `User`.`id`,
                `User`.`name`,
                `User`.`email`,
                `User`.`password`,
                `User`.`salt`,
                `User`.`role_id`,
                `User`.`avatar`,
                `User`.`photo`,
                `User`.`created`,
                `User`.`last_login`,
                `User`.`search_city`,
                `User`.`photo_count`,
                `User`.`friend_count`,
                `User`.`notification_count`,
                `User`.`friend_request_count`,
                `User`.`blog_count`,
                `User`.`topic_count`,
                `User`.`group_count`,
                `User`.`event_count`,
                `User`.`conversation_user_count`,
                `User`.`video_count`,
                `User`.`gender`,
                `User`.`birthday`,
                `User`.`active`,
                `User`.`confirmed`,
                `User`.`code`,
                `User`.`notification_email`,
                `User`.`timezone`,
                `User`.`ip_address`,
                `User`.`privacy`,
                `User`.`username`,
                `User`.`about`,
                `User`.`featured`,
                `User`.`lang`,
                `User`.`hide_online`,
                `User`.`cover`,
                `User`.`approved`,
                `User`.`is_social`,
                `User`.`has_active_subscription`,
                `User`.`receive_message_from_non_friend`,
                `User`.`send_email_when_send_message`,
                `User`.`request_friend_email`,
                `User`.`notification_setting`,
                `User`.`profile_type_id`,
                `User`.`package_select`,
                `User`.`who_can_see_gender`,
                `User`.`chat_count`

         FROM `mooprod`.`users` AS `User`
         WHERE `User`.`active` = 1
           AND `User`.id > 0
         ORDER BY `User`.`id` desc
         LIMIT 15, 15
     ) User
         LEFT JOIN `mooprod`.`roles` AS `Role` ON (`User`.`role_id` = `Role`.`id`)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the `JOIN` (or `LEFT JOIN`), the Optimizer can simply use `INDEX(active, id)` to handle all of the WHERE, ORDER BY, OFFSET, and LIMIT.  But, with the `JOIN`, it punts and does the entire `JOIN`, sorts the results, and only then does `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`.

If a "user" can have only one "role", then there is a workaround:

```
SELECT u.*, role....
    FROM ( SELECT ... FROM user WHERE... ORDER BY... LIMIT ... ) AS u
    LEFT JOIN role ON ...
```

In that formulation, it should be able to use the index to look at only 30 rows (`OFFSET+LIMIT`) to build a 15-row (`LIMIT`) temp table (alias `u`), then join only 15 times to `role`.

Using `OFFSET` for "pagination" is problematic.  I discuss that [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination) and provide a workaround ("remember where you left off").

Comment: I definitely agree for `left off` idea in blog. But should the sql optimizer not able to convert between the two forms ?

Comment: @GauravShah - The two methods do not always produce same results.  Consider the effect of an insert or delete in first 15 rows.  Also, there are 2 _separate_ issues:  the join forcing a sort and `left off` avoiding reading the `OFFSET` rows.

Comment: sorry I didn't explain well. I meant to ask should the sql optimizer not be able to convert `join` to a `subquery(with filter) + join` , since it already know that at the max 1 row will join on roles. And that is because I am joining on role.id which is primary key. In that case sql knew upfront that one user will join with only one role and hence there will be no fanout.

Comment: @GauravShah - MySQL's Optimizer is not that sophisticated.  Many of the answers I give on this (and other) forum are workarounds for inadequacies of the Optimizer.  Or, as mentioned in my Comment, workarounds _given knowledge of the data_.